# asp.net treeview in iframe disappears

Tags: html, asp.net, treeview

I have a page with iframe. In the iframe page I have asp.net treeview control. When I click the node with the  #  (eg: General#) at the end, the iframe page completely disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this problem may be due to  style of iframe .set style as

> position: absolute;